# Importing Products in csv file - empty columns

Tags: import, csv

I am currently adding all my products into a `csv` file ready to import into my store. To get the template i exported my existing products and am using that csv as the template which contains every single column.

I have a lot of empty columns such as...

```
custom_design_from
manufacturer
minimal_price
msrp
special_price
```

etc..

Do i need to include these empty columns? If i remove them will that mess up my import?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need these columns, the only required columns you need are the attributes that are required in the backend.

So in a base install of Magento, you need "`description`", "`name`", "`price`", "`sku`", "`status`", "`tax_class_id`", "`visibility`", and "`weight`". Below is a picture of the required options in a clean install of `Magento EE 1.14` (so there are a few additional required fields as you can see).

[image: Required Options]

Many developers, will delete these columns from the CSV if we are not using them.

I would suggest using OpenOffice to create your CSV and make sure you select the option to "quote all text fields". Microsoft Excel can work, however I have noticed a lot of formatting issues that can screw up data (especially if you use Office for Mac).

Comment: Great thanks! And just to confirm it doesnt matter on the order that i have the columns/attributes in my csv file?

Comment: For the most part, I would keep the beginning of the file the same. I am digging in the code right now to double check.